# Android app to change default bluetooth music player

Tags: android, music, bluetooth

When I turn on my bluetooth stereo, it automatically connects to my bluetooth Android device and starts playing music.  It works great.

What's not great, is that it always launches the wrong music player.

Can anyone recommend an Android app that allows the user to select the default music player for bluetooth connections?

Must be compatible with KitKat.

Prefer an app that is not always running in the background, eating up precious RAM (but this is not a requirement).

Prefer recommendations for gratis (free of charge) apps, but recommendations for paid apps are welcome too.

Comment: Have you tried any of the [default app changers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_5)?

Comment: @Izzy  I've tried several of the default app changers, but so far all the ones I've tried only change the default app for specific file types, not for specific actions like connecting to a bluetooth stereo.

Comment: Ah, I see. Next suggestion: apps for [Headset Control](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_headset). Those often let you define which app to launch when the headphones are connected. Not sure which ones work with Bluetooth headsets, though.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  I'll take a look at a few of those too.